# IS it possible to turn this into a external .js

Tags: javascript, external

Can i turn this into an external script?

```
<center>
Users online:

<blink>
<sup>
<form>
<TABLE style="background-color:white" border="2"> 
<TD><div id="text"></div></TD>
</TABLE>
</form>
</sup>
</blink>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
Function.prototype.allowSleep = function(n) {
  var i, f;
  if (!/^[$\w]+$/.test(n)) return;
  i = 0;
  f = this.toString().replace(/sleep\((.*?)\);/g , function(f,t) {i++; return n+".f"+i+" = function() {"+n+".func"+i+"();};\nsleep("+t+","+n+".f"+i+");\n"+(i==1?"":"}\n")+n+".func" + i +" = function() {";});
  eval(n+'='+f+'\n}');
}
sleep = function(t,f) {
  if (f === undefined) return;
  setTimeout(f,t);
}

afunc = function() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '1';
  sleep(2000);
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '2';
  sleep(2030);
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '3';

}
afunc.allowSleep('afunc'); // comment
afunc();
</script>
```

I save as .js but i get an error on line 2...

What are .js and how do i make them? xD

I just want to be able to hide my code basically

would i have to click a button to show this or will it appear on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not save html in .js file, just put following part in your. js and include it:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Function.prototype.allowSleep = function(n) {
  var i, f;
  if (!/^[$\w]+$/.test(n)) return;
  i = 0;
  f = this.toString().replace(/sleep\((.*?)\);/g , function(f,t) {i++; return n+".f"+i+" = function() {"+n+".func"+i+"();};\nsleep("+t+","+n+".f"+i+");\n"+(i==1?"":"}\n")+n+".func" + i +" = function() {";});
  eval(n+'='+f+'\n}');
}
sleep = function(t,f) {
  if (f === undefined) return;
  setTimeout(f,t);
}

afunc = function() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '1';
  sleep(2000);
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '2';
  sleep(2030);
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '3';

}
afunc.allowSleep('afunc'); // comment
afunc();
</script>
```